# How do I make current menu item active in asp.net webforms masterpage using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, master-pages

How to current menu active

i.e. if i selected and go to that page then the dropdown menu need to active(   `<li class="active treeview">`) in dynamically in asp .net c#.

I want by using jquery or javascript in c#.

All the leftside dropdown list are available in masterpage.

```
      <li class="treeview" id="settingId" runat="server">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                                <span>SETTING</span>

                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>CATEGORY MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>ADD CATEGORY</a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>EMAIL MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>CHANGE PASSWORD</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
 <li class="treeview" id="portfolioId" runat="server">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
                            <span>PORTFOLIO</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>PROJECT MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>ADD PROJECT</a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>PRODUCT MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>ADD PRODUCT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a hidden field in the master page that holds the id of the current tab (parent `li`).  Then set the value of that hidden field in the content pages.

Use the hidden field's value to determine which tab to highlight.  This code assumes the parent `ul` has `id="MasterMenu"` and does **not** have `runat="server"`.  Also that the hidden field has `id="CurrentTab"`.

```
function highlightTab() {
    var currentTab;

    //Get the id of the current tab from the hidden field
    currentTab = $('#CurrentTab').val();

    if (currentTab !== null) {
        //Remove the active-treeview class from all top level li elements
        $('#MasterMenu').children('li').removeClass('active-treeview');

        //Set the active-treeview class to the current tab
        $('#' + currentTab).addClass('active-treeview');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is an example of a hidden field that you would put on your master page.  I'm making it available to the code behind by adding the `runat="server"` attribute. When a control has `runat="server"`, .NET will rename the id when it renders the page.  To stop this behavior so you can easily access the hidden field in JavaScript add the `ClientIDMode="static"` attribute.

```
<asp:HiddenField id="CurrentTab" value="" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

In the page load event of your content pages set the value of that hidden field to the id of the tab you want highlighted for that page.

```
HiddenField currentTab;
currentTab = (HiddenField)this.Master.FindControl("CurrentTab");
currentTab.Value = "settingId";
```

Comment: You can put a hidden field in the master page that holds the id of the current tab (parent li). Then set the value of that hidden field in the content pages.

How???can you give me some example???

Comment: How to get settingId dynamically??currentTab.Value = "settingId";

Comment: For First li id is settingId,for second li id is portfolioId...there is 10 li in my project..so in master page how can i use currentTab.Value = "settingId";??

Comment: You set `currentTab.Value` in the individual content pages not in the master page.  So in the CATEGORY MANAGEMENT, ADD CATEGORY, EMAIL MANAGEMENT and CHANGE PASSWORD content pages you would set `currentTab.Value = "settingId"`.  In the PROJECT MANAGEMENT, ADD PROJECT, PRODUCT MANAGEMENT, and ADD PRODUCT content pages you would set `currentTab.Value = "portfolioId"`

Comment: In Your method i need to write down HiddenField currentTab;
currentTab = (HiddenField)this.Master.FindControl("CurrentTab");
currentTab.Value = "settingId"; or  HiddenField currentTab;
currentTab = (HiddenField)this.Master.FindControl("CurrentTab");
currentTab.Value = "portfolioId"; in every respective pages..???Otherwise if i define only currentTab.Value = "settingId"; or portfolioId it gives an error.(the currentTab dpes not exist in the current context)

Comment: How to highlight the tab??

Answer (score -1):

In each page need to change the current id (suppose `leftsidebar_settingId`)

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                debugger;
                //$('#leftsidebar_portfolioId').addClass('treeview');
                $('#leftsidebar_settingId').addClass('treeview active');
            });

        </script>
```